# MatNativeDateModule, MatMomentDateModule not found in angular 9.1.1

Tags: angular-material

Old angular/material has those two modules. but angular/material 9.1.1 version has not those two module. I got below error. Anyone has any idea how to import those two module

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: MatDatepicker: No provider found for DateAdapter. You must import one of the following modules at your application root: MatNativeDateModule, MatMomentDateModule, or provide a custom implementation.
Error: MatDatepicker: No provider found for DateAdapter. You must import one of the following modules at your application root: MatNativeDateModule, MatMomentDateModule, or provide a custom implementation.
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Angullar 8,9

```
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
```

Angular 7 and below

```
import { MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material';
```

You need to import both MatDatepickerModule and MatNativeDateModule under imports and add MatDatepickerModule under providers

```
imports: [
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule 
  ],
  providers: [  
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule  
  ],
```

Comment: Are you sure that it has to be included in the `providers`?

Comment: For my it worked out by including this simply in the `imports`.

Comment: Can you use MatDatepickerModule as provider in component level ?

Comment: I'm importing that module in `imports` on the module level, as you're showing, and then on a component level only its properties.

Comment: Usually adding module to providers is not necessary as importing does it automatically.

Answer (score 4):

In case you're looking for the `MatMomentDateModule`, it does not come by default, you will need to install
[`@angular/material-moment-adapter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/material-moment-adapter) separately

```
npm install --save @angular/material-moment-adapter
```

In case you face the issue that the peer dependency `Moment.js` is missing, install it with

```
npm install --save-dev moment
```

Then go ahead and import the `MatMomentDateModule` in the module file

```
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatMomentDateModule, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatMomentDateModule

    ],
    providers: [
        {provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: {useUtc: true}}
    ]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Read more at [Angular Material Datepicker component](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)